# grouping by the first letter of names in return statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am returning a statement that gets a number of users to display all in which are already in alphabetical order. I would like to display this result also adding to it the ability to group all names that start with the same letter together so i could create some sort of label or index to it.

Code:

```
return new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum).GroupBy(x=>x.Name.Substring(0,1));
```

Problem: the return statement throws an error stating:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,ProjectName.Shared.Models.Views.User>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectName.Shared.Models.Views.User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

How can i go about fixing this?

Comment: Please show the code that results in this error, and the type that you expect the result to have.

Comment: Do we get to see the code you are using?

Comment: Methods that declare a return type must respect that return type in all `return` statements. You are not doing this. _Metaphor: You promised to return cars, but instead you're returning boats which contain cars._ It's obvious that you need to do whatever grouping you said you were going to do, later, outside the method that you're saying `throws` you an error. (btw: That's a compiler error, not a runtime exception)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry about that forgot to add it in.

Comment: So you need to return a list of lists? Users groups for each letter.

Comment: @UfukHaciogullan yes i need to return lets say all the users that start with A and then B and so on

Comment: @Masriyah If you need to return all users that start with A then B and so on, you need ordering, not grouping.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight even if it is already ordered from stored procedure?

Comment: @Masriyah If SP returns them to you ordered the way that you like, why bother re-ordering them in memory? All `A`s will be before `B`s, `B`s before `C`s, and so on. Grouping implies constructing multiple collections, not just setting the specific order.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight i don't need to order i want to group so that all names that start with A are under the A header and so on so i am just changing the appearance not really sorting

Comment: @Masriyah If the data is sorted, grouping visually is a matter of detecting boundaries, i.e. the positions in the ordered sequence where the `A` names end and the `B` names start, etc.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight is there a different approach to this other than what i am possibly trying to do now?

Comment: Of course there is: you could do grouping of pre-ordered items on the displaying end by detecting the spots where the first letter of the name changes.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight if you could possibly lead me to an example that will be awesome - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the statement creates a grouping, but you are trying to return a plain list of users.

There are two ways of fixing this:

- You may want to return an `IDictionary<string,IList<User>>` instead of `IEnumerable<User>` (you could use `char` as the key as well) , or
- You may want to order users by name, instead of grouping, if you want to return a plain list.

Here is how you make it an `IDictionary<string,IList<User>>`:

```
IDictionary<string,IList<User>> res = new UserService()
    .GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum)
    .GroupBy(x=>x.Name.Substring(0,1))
    .ToDictionary(
        g => g.Key
    ,   g => (IList<User>)g.ToList()
    );
```

**EDIT :** (in response to this comment: "I want to group so that all names that start with A are under the A header and so on so I am just changing the appearance not really sorting")

In cases like this, you do not *need* grouping (although you can certainly make use of it if you wish to do so). You could order the data instead, in your LINQ, in your SP, or otherwise, and then provide the headers visually by inserting then at the boundaries between the names that start in different letters.

Here is a very crude example of doing it in a program that prints to console. You should be able to adapt it to your particular visuals with little work:

```
// I assume that you know how to write the GetUsersSortedByName method
IList<User> sortedUsers = GetUsersSortedByName();
char? lastSeenFirstLetter = null;
// The loop below assumes that there are no users with empty names
foreach (User u in sortedUsers) {
    if (u.Name[0] != lastSeenFirstLetter) {
        Console.WriteLine("==== Header: users with names in {0}", u.Name[0]);
        lastSeenFirstLetter = u.Name[0];
    }
    Console.WriteLine(u); // Finally, display the user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the appropriate type from the method:

```
public IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, User>> GetUserIndex()
{
    return new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum).GroupBy(x=>x.Name.Substring(0,1));
}
```

Then you can iterate each group like this:

```
var userIndex = GetUserIndex();

foreach(var group in userIndex)
{
    string currentLetter = group.Key;
    foreach(User user in group)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: i am thinking of placing the foreach loop inside the GetUserIndex() method and set var userIndex = new UserService().... and what i place in the inner foreach loop i would return it

Comment: @Masriyah You would need to return another type from your method. IGrouping interface is suitable for your case, you will get the starting letter as the key and the users for that letter.

Comment: I would create an IEnumerable list and then add to id what i get from user in group foreach statement

Answer (score 0):

> Problem: the return statement throws an error stating:
>
> *`Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Linq.IGrouping<string,ProjectName.Shared.Models.Views.User>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ProjectName.Shared.Models.Views.User>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`*
>
> How can i go about fixing this?

Try this:

```
    return new UserService()
            .GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum)
            .GroupBy(x=>x.Name.Substring(0,1))
            .Select(g=>g); //<-----
```

Comment: I think this query won't change the ordering. Maybe OP is trying to return groups.

Answer (score 0):

You said you have a method and you would like it to return something like this:

```
return new UserService()
         .GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum)
         .GroupBy(x=>x.Name.Substring(0,1));
```

Based on the compiler error you're getting, it is obvious that your method looks something like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ProjectName.Shared.Models.Views.User> GetTheUsers() {
    // do something here...

    return new UserService()
             .GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum)
             .GroupBy(x=>x.Name.Substring(0,1));
}
```

You can't do that. Leave it like you designed it initially, without the grouping:

```
public IEnumerable<ProjectName.Shared.Models.Views.User> GetTheUsers() {
    // do something here...

    return new UserService().GetUsers(id.Value, pageNumber: _pageNum);
}
```

and then, when you call it, do the grouping on the spot:

```
public void Foo() {
    // do something here...

    var ungroupedUsers = GetTheUsers();

    var groupedUsers = ungroupedUsers.GroupBy(x=>x.Name.Substring(0,1))

    // and now use the groupedUsers accordingly

}
```